# Tensorflow error using my own data

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I've been playing with the Tensorflow library doing the tutorials. Now I wanted to play with my own data, but I fail horribly. This is perhaps a noob question but I can't figure it out.

I'm using this example: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3%20-%20Neural%20Networks/convolutional_network.py

I want to use my own images, for converting my images to use with tensorflow i'm using this: https://github.com/HamedMP/ImageFlow/blob/master/ImageFlow.py

Now I change the parameters in the example from this:

```
 n_input = 784
 n_classes = 10
```

to this:

```
 n_input = 9216
 n_classes = 2
```

I did that because my images are 96 * 96 and there are only 2 classes of my images

I also change the weights and biases to the numbers I need.

I read the data like this:

```
batch_xs = imgReader.read_images(pathname);
```

imgReader being the ImageFlow file

but when I try to run it I gives me an error:

```
 ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (104, 96, 96, 1) for Tensor
 u'Placeholder:0', which has shape (Dimension(None), Dimension(9216))
```

I feel like i'm overlooking something small but I don't see it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This error arises because the shape of the data that you're trying to feed (104 x 96 x 96 x 1) does not match the shape of the input placeholder (`batch_size` x 9216, where `batch_size` may be variable).

To make it work, add the following line before running a training step:

```
batch_xs = np.reshape(batch_xs, (-1, 9216))
```

This uses numpy to reshape the images read in, which are 4-D arrays of `batch_size` x h x w x channels, into a `batch_size` x 9216 element matrix as expected by the placeholder.

Comment: Glad it worked! Some of the shape stuff can be quite subtle, so we'll try to work on the error messages.

Comment: By the way, can make reshaping part of your graph with tf.reshape()

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading tensorflow through pip.