# Difficulty adapting Keras example to customer data

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I'm trying to run the following network with Keras, powered by a TensorFlow backend. It's an adaptation of the "VGG-like" convnet from http://keras.io/examples/:

```
import os 
import sys
import json
import model_control 
from numpy import loadtxt, asarray
from pandas import read_csv
from scipy.ndimage import imread
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from keras.layers import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import SGD

Y_train = loadtxt(model_control.y_train_file, delimiter=',', dtype = int)

train_files = os.listdir(model_control.train_img_path)
train_files = ['%s/%s' % (model_control.train_img_path, x) for x in train_files if 'jpg' in x]
X_train = asarray([imread(x) for x in train_files])

X_train.shape #..(8144, 128, 256) (a numpy array of 8144 128x256 greyscale, i.e. single-channel, images)
Y_train.shape #..(8144,) (A 1-d numpy array of integer class labels) 

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5, border_mode='valid', input_shape=(1, 128, 256)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 5, 5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5, border_mode='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 5, 5))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(10))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.1, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=1, verbose=1)
```

This produces the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (32, 128, 256) for Tensor u'Placeholder_89:0', which has shape '(?, 1, 128, 256)'
```

I've checked out the following posts but haven't been able to solve this one yet. Any help would be appreciated, along with an explanation of what's going wrong.

  https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/keras-users/Vb7MhSqne0Y
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33974231/tensorflow-error-using-my-own-data

**UPDATE**

Posted this question to the Keras issue board (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2092). There are [Gist](https://gist.github.com/aaronpolhamus/39c7a71151b8560d02dd) and [sample data](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/files/190676/keras_ex_data.zip) links that will allow you to re-create the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. In the script, the following line is needed to "reshape" the input array:

`X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], 1, 128, 256)`

Really, all we're doing here is adding a somewhat redundant channel dimension to make the shape of the array `(8144, 1, 128, 256)` instead of `(8144, 128, 256)`. If we were using an RGB array this wouldn't be redundant at all, since it would be `(8144, 3, 128, 256)`. Bottom line: my input array was missing the channel dimension, which I thought I could get away with omitting for greyscales. Turns out you still need to explicitly define the shape.

Great package. Once fixed the code should execute as-is.